# How can I use a SP_* icon in a custom stylesheet?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Qt's QStyle provides `standardIcon`, which makes it possible to grab the standard icon given a StandardPixmap value:

```
const QStyle * style = QApplication::style();
const QIcon ok       = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DialogOkButton);
```

This is great if you want to set icons by hand with `.setIcon`, for example on QPushButtons or other widgets. However, I want to set the icons in a (external) stylesheet. If the icon was available in `:/images/ok.icon`, that would be quite easy:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPushButton button("Example");
    button.setStyleSheet(
        "icon-size: 32px 32px;"
        "qproperty-icon: url(:/images/ok.icon);" // <--
    );    

    return a.exec();
}
```

However, I want to use `style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DialogOkButton);`, not an icon in the resource system. Is that possible, or do I need to prepare all the icons by hand?

### TL;DR

```
// What I have:
button.setIcon(QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DialogOkButton));

// What I want:
button.setStyleSheet(
  "qproperty-icon: url(some_url);"
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be one of the standard Qt icons:

```
qproperty-icon: url(:/trolltech/styles/commonstyle/images/standardbutton-apply-16.png)
```

You can find all the available icons in `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0/src/gui/styles/images`

> Will the icon get resized correctly if I set it to the `-16.png` variant?

The docs says that the icons will not be scaled up. You can use `-128.png` and it will be scaled down according to `iconSize()`.

> Also, the standardIcon uses the operating system/window manager
>   default icons, whereas the trolltech icons differ. Any way to do this?

You can access OS theme icons via `QIcon::fromTheme()` but that works only for Linux. In OSX and Windows Qt falls back to standard icons from the resources.

If you want to have several icon sizes, be able to use system icons and still fall back to icons from the resources, I suggest you to inherit QPushButton and add a new custom property that will take care of everything.

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString my_icons_set READ iconsSet WRITE setIconsSet)
...
void setIconsSet(QString icons)
{
    // parse the string
}
```

Then in css you can do something like:

```
qproperty-my_icons_set: "fromTheme::dialog-ok, standardIcon::SP_DialogOkButton";
```

Comment: `setIcon` uses the appropriate icon size. Will the icon get resized correctly if I set it to the `-16.png` variant? (I don't have a Qt version installed at the moment). Also, the `standardIcon` uses the operating system/window manager default icons, whereas the trolltech icons differ. Any way to do this? Either way, thanks for your answer.